# using css3 scale blurs the view in metro app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scale

I am trying to scale a DIV to 0.8 times and it is causing the DIV to get blurred.
It seems to working fine in Chrome and Safari but gets blurred in a metro app.

I tried using some Jquery transform2d plugins thinking that may be CSS rendering is slower,but the blur effect was there in that also.

Can someone suggest a solution to this problem.

Comment: Does it happen with all image types? png. jpg. gif?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the original div a scale down and then just scaling it up the actual size therefore making it appear to scale up!

Comment: i could not get what you mean.how would that prevent the blurring?

Comment: The div is blurring because you are stretching it. If you have a big image, then scale it down, when you scale it up again it wont blur because your increasing it to its original size!

Comment: but I am scaling it to 0.8 so I don't get how the DIV is getting stretched.